# I want to create a SQL new column using CASE and WHEN

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the table that I have

| cnt_dealno | dealno | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 3,000 |
| 2 | ABC | 3,000 |
| 3 | ABC | 3,000 |
| 1 | DEF | 5,000 |
| 2 | DEF | 5,000 |

This is how I think I would code it

```
select
case when cnt_dealno = '1' then amount
else amount = 0
end as new_amount
from tab
```

What I try to do is when `cnt_dealno = 1`, then the amount is not changing. But when the `cnt_dealno` is not equal to `1`, then the amount will become `0`.

Is there any way to code this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
SQL> with test (cnt_dealno, dealno, amount) as
  2    (select 1, 'ABC', 3000 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'ABC', 3000 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'ABC', 3000 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'DEF', 5000 from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'DEF', 5000 from dual
  7    )
  8  select cnt_dealno, dealno, amount,
  9    --
 10    case when cnt_dealno = 1 then amount
 11         else 0
 12    end as new_amount
 13  from test;

CNT_DEALNO DEA     AMOUNT NEW_AMOUNT
---------- --- ---------- ----------
         1 ABC       3000       3000
         2 ABC       3000          0
         3 ABC       3000          0
         1 DEF       5000       5000
         2 DEF       5000          0

SQL>
```

Why do you think you need PL/SQL?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this one works like a charm. I tried to do it in PL/SQL therefore I think that I need PL/SQL with it. Sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.